# Trouble playing and ripping CD audio files on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit

Tags: sound, permissions, rhythmbox, cd, cd-ripping

I'm trying to rip audio files from a CD onto a subdirectory of the Music directory. My Linux 12.04 LTS 32-bit came with Audacity, Brasero, Banshee, and Rhythmbox. (Yes, not one, four players. Go figure.) I tried playing the audio files with Audacity, Banshee, and Rhythmbox, but they all would freeze, so I would have to force-quit them. I was thinking about copy-and-paste, but I noticed that the icons of those files have a lock on them. So I tried this:

```
andrey@owner-VPCSC1AFM:~/.gvfs/cdda mount on sr0$ sudo cp ./* ~/Music/Scott\ Walker/Tilt/
[sudo] password for andrey:
cp: cannot stat `./Track 1.wav': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat `./Track 2.wav': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat `./Track 3.wav': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat `./Track 4.wav': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat `./Track 5.wav': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat `./Track 6.wav': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat `./Track 7.wav': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat `./Track 8.wav': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat `./Track 9.wav': Permission denied
```

... where `~/.gvfs/cdda mount on sr0` is actually the `Audio Disc` feature. I checked out the files' permissions:

```
andrey@owner-VPCSC1AFM:~/.gvfs/cdda mount on sr0$ ls -l
total 588881
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 70223776 Dec 31 1969 Track 1.wav
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 63852208 Dec 31 1969 Track 2.wav
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 93532096 Dec 31 1969 Track 3.wav
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 64468432 Dec 31 1969 Track 4.wav
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 55667248 Dec 31 1969 Track 5.wav
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 81877936 Dec 31 1969 Track 6.wav
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 89611312 Dec 31 1969 Track 7.wav
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 55260352 Dec 31 1969 Track 8.wav
-r-------- 1 andrey owner 28518112 Dec 31 1969 Track 9.wav
```

... and tried to manually change their permissions, and came up with this:

```
andrey@owner-VPCSC1AFM:~/.gvfs/cdda mount on sr0$ chmod 500 ./*
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 1.wav': Operation not supported
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 2.wav': Operation not supported
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 3.wav': Operation not supported
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 4.wav': Operation not supported
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 5.wav': Operation not supported
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 6.wav': Operation not supported
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 7.wav': Operation not supported
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 8.wav': Operation not supported
chmod: changing permissions of `./Track 9.wav': Operation not supported
```

Is it not allowing me to change permissions because I did not do this as a super-user? So, I tried this:

```
andrey@owner-VPCSC1AFM:~/.gvfs/cdda mount on sr0$ sudo chmod 500 ./*
[sudo] password for andrey:
chmod: cannot access `./Track 1.wav': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./Track 2.wav': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./Track 3.wav': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./Track 4.wav': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./Track 5.wav': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./Track 6.wav': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./Track 7.wav': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./Track 8.wav': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./Track 9.wav': Permission denied
```

================================================== ===========

Alternatively, I could simply install a ripper application, like Asunder (source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185451). I've installed Asunder, but for some reason it took a really long time (about 30 mins) to rip the whole CD. If you know a better ripper application (stable, all-audio-formats -friendly ripper application that does not take an eternity to rip a CD), please comment.

================================================================

So, as you can see, not only do I have trouble playing and ripping CD audio files, but I also have trouble changing their permissions. Any help to redeem this issue would be much appreciated ... before I stupidly install one more extra media player that might make playing the files happen, or an unnecessary ripping program. I did find some similar threads on the forum (https://askubuntu.com/search?q=rip+audio), but they had quite different scenarios, not what I was looking for.

---

I'm definitely using Ubuntu.

- Audacity: 2.0.0-1ubuntu0.1;
- Banshee: 2.4.1-3ubuntu1~precise2;
- Rhythmbox: 2.96-0ubuntu4.3

I dont remember how I installed these.

Comment: Think about it: a CD is physically read-only, you can't change permissions. Second: you can't filecopy audio from CD. Third: Brasero is very buggy, use k3b to rip the CD. Fourth: If your CD drive has difficulty reading the CD, none of the earlier mentioned points will help. Try another computer to rip/play the CD.

Comment: Excellent comment. Quite a few things I didn't know. k3b? Noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Hope it works for you too :)

Install required software packages using apt-get.

```
$ sudo apt-get install cdparanoia lame sox
```

Display verbosely about search for CD+ROM drive and tabulate contents using ‘cdparanoia’

```
$ sudo cdparanoia -vsQ
```

Indicate progress and extract each track in CD+ROM to one .wav file each.

```
$ sudo cdparanoia -B
```

Convert .wav to high quality .mp3.

```
$ sudo lame --preset extreme ./track01.cdda.wav ./FileNameOfYourChoice.mp3
```

Play .wav file.

```
$ play track01.cdda.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a permissions problem here.

You can try and become root and do it from there with:

`sudo -i`

Enter in your password and then go back to the location and attempt to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had significant ttrouble getting audio ripping working using 14.04 (which is now the latest stable release). RipOff [doesn't find any plugins to encode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517603/ripoff-0-8-3-not-finding-any-plugins), asunder [freezes very frequently](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/asunder/+bug/791463?comments=all) etc.

The asunder problems at least are fixed in [Doug McMahon's CD Ripping PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/cdda1) and that also contains a version of rubyripper - I recommend using this PPA