# RipOff 0.8.3 not finding ANY plugins

Tags: software-center, plugins

As of upgrading 14.04 I've had a problem with RipOff (i.e. 0.8.3).  I get

"No valid RipOff encoding plugin could be found"

Under Preferences/Plugins lo-and-behold no plugins - not even the free ones! The Preferences and About buttons under the empty plugin list are greyed out :( Presumably there I could configure where to find any plugins.

The Software Center says I have RipOff Installed (which I do), the Synaptic Manager says I have it installed, including the MP3 ripoff library in the hope that that might work.
I've completely uninstalled, including removing the mp3 library using the Synaptic Package Manager, and reinstalled with no success.

I presume the plugins are somewhere, just not where ripoff is looking for them? Anyone had this problem?  I've not done anything fancy with this machine (I rely on it!)

Incidentally, I've tried extracting tracks from my CDs from Rhythmbox, and I get something about the operation is not supported by the back end. Does something get removed on upgrading?  On upgrading, Rhythmbox seemed to rewrite the track titles for the CDs I have in my collection. This is a separate problem, but may indicate some other symptom?

Comment: I have the same problem. Note that the mp3 library is installed at `/usr/lib/${arch}/plugins/liblame.so`, whereas ripoff is actually looking at `/usr/lib/ripoff/plugins/` - symlinking it there doesn't help though; ripoff seems to scan that directory for files but not actually load the plugins from it...

Comment: I've filed a bug for this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ripoff/+bug/1433999

Comment: RipOff doesn't seem to have had a release since 2007; I'm suspecting this won't be fixed, and am rather using the software in Doug McMahon's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/cdda1 - that contains fixes to the problems I had with asunder.

Answer (score 5):

I thought I'd answered this before, but can't find this answer here, so here it is again:

I've started using Asunder - brilliant tool ;)  As brilliant as RipOff used to be :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidFoerster this is the OP of the post, the solution is apparently using an alternative,

Comment: Asunder is beautiful, thanks. You're absolutely right, it's as good as RipOff used to be, if not better.